# How to format HTML files to get defined names in Excel (copy-paste from web browser)?

Tags: html, excel

At work I am in charge of developing some basic Python scripts which export results into text files. Then the text files are imported into an Excel spreadsheet my colleagues are familiar with.

I realized these Python scripts could easily generate .html files with `<table>` elements instead of .dat text files. These html files could be opened with the Internet browser and then exported to a new Excel spreadsheet using copy/paste.

Somehow, using the tag `<a name=Defined_name></a>Value` results in having the cell provided with "Value" being referenced as "Defined_name". I see a great opportunity to upgrade in having defined names directly created when importing a .html web page.

Below is a basic example of a .html file that results in generating defined names in Excel (2007 and over) :

```
<table>
   <tbody> <!-- Corps du tableau -->
       <tr>
           <td><A name=Nom_1></A>Carmen</td>
           <td><A name=Age_1></A>33 ans</td>
           <td><A name=Pays_1></A>Espagne</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
           <td><A name=Nom_2></A>Michelle</a></td>
           <td><A name=Age_2></A>26 ans</td>
           <td><A name=Pays_2></A>États-Unis</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
           <td><A name=Nom_3></A>François</td>
           <td><A name=Age_3></A>43 ans</td>
           <td><A name=Pays_3></A>France</td></A>
       </tr>
       <tr>
           <td><A name=Nom_4></A>Martine</td>
           <td><A name=Age_4></A>34 ans</td>
           <td><A name=Pays_4></A>France</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
           <td><A name=Nom_5></A>Jonathan</td>
           <td><A name=Age_5></A>13 ans</td>
           <td><A name=Pays_5></A>Australie</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
           <td><A name=Nom_6></A>Xu</td>
           <td><A name=Age_6></A>19 ans</td>
           <td><A name=Pays_6></A>Chine</td>
       </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

I am looking for a way to have defined names for a range of cells (row, column or array). The only things I can reference are single cells.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Why not use python to just create an excel file ?

Comment: This would be better but I have no clue how an excel file is formatted. When I open it on NP++ it's completely messed up.
I suppose I cannot write a .xlsx file the same way I write a .txt file on Python

Comment: Can you post the code (the relevant part only) you have that creates the text file.

Comment: Well that's just basic stuff using something like :
with open(out_file, 'w') as f:
            f.write(line)

Comment: Sorry , I meant how are the lines of data created, are they in  a loop ?

Answer (score 0):

With `openpyxl` you could create the workbook using python

```py
import openpyxl

# create a workbook
wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
ws = wb.worksheets[0]

# define a named range
dn = openpyxl.workbook.defined_name
rng = dn.DefinedName('data', attr_text='Sheet!$A$1:$J$10')
wb.defined_names.append(rng)

# add some data
for r in range(1,11):
  for c in range (1,11):
     ws.cell(r,c).value = r + (c-1)*10

wb.save("myworkbook.xlsx")
print("workbook created")
```